# Deserialze json with a wrapper keyword with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am using `retroft` and `gson` for request/response in my app.
The json structure I get from server for json object is like:

```
{
"data": {
"name": "Rogelio Volkman",
"address": "27299 Will Bridge Suite 058\nWest Reubenhaven, MI 00736",
"lat": 54.65,
"lng": 111.75,
"phone": "+26(4)5015498663",
"user": {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Mehrdad"
    }
  ]
   }
  }
}
```

As you see every model is wrapped around `data` keyword.
For json array response the result is like:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "name": "Rogelio Volkman",
  "address": "27299 Will Bridge Suite 058\nWest Reubenhaven, MI 00736",
  "lat": 54.65,
  "lng": 111.75,
  "phone": "+26(4)5015498663",
  "user": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Mehrdad"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "name": "Jovani Ritchie",
  "address": "920 Winona Lake\nAlisashire, GA 27145",
  "lat": -32.57,
  "lng": 134.6,
  "phone": "442.530.4166",
  "user": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Mehrdad"
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want to Create a class which deserialises theses responses with GSON, but I can't `implement` `JsonDeserializer<DataObjectModel>` since in the `deserialize` method I don't know wheter to call `je.getJsonObject("data")` or `je.getJsonArray("data")`.
How to deserialize this response?

Answer (score 0):

"data" is a JSON array, that's why you need to use je.getJsonArray("data").

If you are using retrofit, then you can deserialise this JSON in POJO with a help of GSON Converter Factory.
POJO you can create with a help of this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Good tutorial on retrofit for your needs is here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Answered my question without reading the question first? I was asking for deserializing with ``data`` keyword

Comment: @Mehrdad, I'm sorry, but your writing style is very confusing to me and it is hard to understand what you actually want in your question. Nevertheless, you can use described approach from my answer and it will work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO class for the response i.e create a model class and use the @SerializedName annotation like below

```
public class Data{
  @SerializedName("name")
   String name;
  @SerializedName("address")
   String address;
  @SerializedName("lat")
   double lat;
   .....
}
```

And to deserialize all you have to do is use the below code

```
  String dataString = responseObject.getString("data");
  Data[] dataArray = new Gson().fromJson(dataString,Data[].class);
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: That would be OK, but since I'm using ``retrofit`` data is handled in callback methods, I don't have access to response as plain ``String``

Comment: You get the jsonObject response from retrofit right. You can use object.toString();

Answer (score 0):

Make two gson model classes -

```
    Class UserObject {
        @SerializedName("data")
        User user;
    }
    Class User {
        // User object
    }
    Class UserArray {
         @Serialized("data")
         User[] list;
    }

    Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
    if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
      //you have an object
       new Gson().fromJson(json,UserObject.class); 
    } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
       new Gson.fromJson(json,UserArray.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its perfectly fine to do:

```
@Override
        public DataObjectModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
                                           JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

            JsonElement data = ((JsonObject) json).get("data");
            if(data.isJsonArray()) {
               JsonArray dataArr = data.getAsJsonArray();
                //do smth with array
            } else {
                JsonObject dataObj = data.getAsJsonObject();
                //do smth with object
            }
            ...
```

Comment: how do I register deserializer class for ``List`` datatype of model. I tried ``new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Museum.class, new DataObjectDeserializer()).registerTypeAdapter(Museum[].class, new DataObjectDeserializer()).create();`` But it didn't work

Comment: what exacly didnt work? you need to pass created gson to the converter factory when creating it "GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)"